# How do most people organize code within an application (sub folders)?

Tags: asp.net, winforms, silverlight, wcf, sql-server-2005

In a website, I see some developers put code into app_code, and sometimes appcode (due to some bug), other files into DataModel, and other files into miscellaneous folders.

Is there a standard approach to organizing code within an application?

How is it different between an ASP.NET, MVC, Silverlight, Console, Database, and WCF application?   The reason I mention WCF is because many people seem to have a shared types library that is linked between the server and client code.

Where can I learn these common practices without having to try, fail, and try again.  I'd rather just learn it once from the experts.

Comment: Unfortunately one criteria for becoming an expert is to have tried, failed, and tried again, many times :)

Comment: I don't want to be an expert, I just want to work well alongside them.  Learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the most standard well organized is MVC framework. For anything else, mostly i organize folders as namespace.

eg companyName.projectName.folderName

- myCompany.StackOverFlow.Extension
- myCompany.StackOverFlow.OpenID

Comment: FxCop naming rules can be helpful. It can also tell you if a namespace contains too few classes/interfaces and suggest merging namespaces into one. Try to keep your namespaces mean and lean, not too fragmented (into thousands of classes/interfaces) nor too small.

Answer (score 1):

There is no set in stone 'best practice' standard for organizing namespaces.  My personal approach to keeping projects organized is to limit the content of any directory/namespace to about 20 items.  This means I can fit the full contents of a folder into my screen, and also see every other item surrounding it (assuming other folders are collapsed).

On the other hand, lots of folders without much content can make navigation difficult as well.

Another thing you should do is to separate your solution into projects based on dependencies. For example if you are using m-v-vm, you should have a project for each of Model, View, and ViewModel.

Files placed in AppCode should only be files directly relevant to the presentation modules.  Other files (ie ViewModel, Model, Controller etc depending on the framework you're using) would be preferably placed in separate projects.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "WCF the Manual Way…the Right Way" http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0809101